# Unable to register the PushPlugin in app using Phonegap Build?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to implement a functionality in my Phonegap app such that it can receive Push notifications and I am referring the following blog to do so:

> http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/

I have got the "Google Cloud Messaging Project ID" and the "Google Cloud Messaging API Key for above Project ID"(needed for server)
I am following Plugin Installation for PhoneGap Build according to which I added

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
```

to my index.html file.

and added

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />
```

to my config.xml file.

I have specified the version of phonegap as 3.1.0 in the config.xml as well

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.4.0" />
```

To register the application with the Google Cloud Messaging service to receive push notifications. I added the code below to the head section of my index.html

```
<script>
        if (window.cordova) {
            if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) == "Android") {


                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

                PushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, { "senderID": "469325418209", "ecb": "onNotificationGCM" });

                function successHandler(result) {
                    alert('Callback Success! Result = ' + result);
                }

                function errorHandler(error) {
                    alert(error);
                }

                function onNotificationGCM(e) {
                    switch (e.event) {
                        case 'registered':
                            if (e.regid.length > 0) {
                                console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                                alert('registration id = ' + e.regid);
                            }
                            break;

                        case 'message':
                            // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
                            alert('message = ' + e.message + ' msgcnt = ' + e.msgcnt);
                            break;

                        case 'error':
                            alert('GCM error = ' + e.msg);
                            break;

                        default:
                            alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    </script>
```

When I build the app using phonegap and run it on my phone it runs normally but the alert 
on either on success or error on failure of PushNotification.register is not being fired when the app is launched.

Am I missing a step or made a mistake in following the steps? Any suggestion or guidance to implement the push notification functionality is appreciated.

Comment: Yes! I was doing a redirect on another page before onNotificationGCM could be called. Changing that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using GCM's browser or android key.

Comment: Yes I am using the Android key but the function does not fire when I run the app.

Comment: Is it successfully recognizing the Android platform?

Comment: You should use pushNotification.register instead of PushNotification.register

Answer (score 0):

you can add the Push  plugin from the `CLI`  which is in github

```
[https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git][1]
```

just  add plugin and follow the steps that is described in github

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git
```

Comment: The plugin seems to be installed but still the function PushNotification.register does not to fire for some reason.

Comment: did it shows an error in the log ?? Have you tried in other devices too ??

Comment: you can go here http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/tutorial-push-notifications-sample-app for further research